# How to access to data row in kendo ui grid column command template?

Tags: telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-mvc, kendo-ui-grid

I want to access to data row in kendo ui grid column command template ,but not found solution to resolve this request.

```js
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns : [{
            field : "firstname",
            title : "First Name"
        }, {
            field : "lastname",
            title : "Last Name"
        }, {
            field : "cellphone",
            title : "Cell Phone"
        }, {
            field : "deskphone",
            title : "Desk Phone"
        }, {
            field : "emailaddress",
            title : "Email Address"
        },
        {
            command : [
            {
                name: "note",
                text: "note",
                template:"<a class='tds-grid-button k-button k-grid-#: name #' title='#: text #'> #: rowData.ID #    <i class='fa fa-comment-o'></i></a>",
                imageClass: "fa fa-comment-o",
                click: note_Clicked
            }
]
});
</script>
```

i want to access to `ID` value from data of row in column command template as : `#: rowData.ID #`

```
template:"<a class='tds-grid-button k-button k-grid-#: name #' title='#: text #'> #: rowData.ID #    <i class='fa fa-comment-o'></i></a>"
```

How to resolve this solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it the way you are.  I think you don't have access to the row data in that manner.
If you replace your rowData.ID with a function call instead, the function only executes twice, *not* once for every rendered row, which means the template is only "executed" during grid initialization.

I found this Telerik forum post that talks about this: http://www.telerik.com/forums/accessing-row-data-in-a-command
Where it is suggested that you use the Grid's dataBound event to change the text on the buttons and they provided a link to a demo Dojo.

Here is a link to a demo where I took the dojo from the forum post and slightly modified the dataBound handler to use the Id from the dataItem to dynamically changed the text on the button.
http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/oVuCo

I'm not sure how else to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution I came to is below.

Instead of column command you can use simple column template where the data are accessible. Like that:

```
                {
                    title: "Status", width: "140px",
                    template: (item) => {
                        if (item.Status == 'Outstanding') {
                            return "<a class='ignore-outstanding' >Outstanding</a>";
                        } else
                            return item.Status;                            
                    }                        
                },
```

And add your click handler in dataBound handler like that:

```
            dataBound: () => {                    
                var grid = $(gridSelector).data("kendoGrid");
                $(gridSelector + cellSelector).click((e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
                    alert(dataItem.YourField);
                });
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
dataSource: {
   data: data,
   schema: {
     model: {
       id: "Id",
       fields:{
          Id: {type: "number"},
          firstname: { type: "string"},
          lastname: { type: "string"},
          cellphone: { type: "string"},
          deskphone: { type: "string"},
          emailaddress: { type: "string"}
          }
        }
     }
},
        columns : [{
                field : "firstname",
                title : "First Name"
            }, {
                field : "lastname",
                title : "Last Name"
            }, {
                field : "cellphone",
                title : "Cell Phone"
            }, {
                field : "deskphone",
                title : "Desk Phone"
            }, {
                field : "emailaddress",
                title : "Email Address"
            },
            {
                command : [
                {
                    name: "note",
                    text: "note",
                    template: "<a class='tds-grid-button k-button k-grid-#=name#' title='#=name#'> 
    #=Id# <i class='fa fa-comment-o'></i></a>"
                }
    ]
    });
    </script>
```

Note-
in place of #=Id# put the primary field you want to set in kendo grid.
i think you have model in kendo grid datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Tanks,
i find my solution to resolve it.

you can use dataBound event of kendo ui grid as follows:

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns : [{
            field : "firstname",
            title : "First Name"
        }, {
            field : "lastname",
            title : "Last Name"
        }, {
            field : "cellphone",
            title : "Cell Phone"
        }, {
            field : "deskphone",
            title : "Desk Phone"
        }, {
            field : "emailaddress",
            title : "Email Address"
        },
        {
            command : [
            {
                name: "note",
                text: "note",
                template:"<a class='tds-grid-button k-button k-grid-#: name #' title='#: text #'> #: rowData.ID #    <i class='fa fa-comment-o'></i></a>",
                imageClass: "fa fa-comment-o",
                click: note_Clicked
            }
],
dataBound: function () {
                        var grid = this;
                        var model;

                        grid.tbody.find("tr[role='row']").each(function () {
                            rowData = grid.dataItem(this);
                            rowData.ID
                            rowData.Name
                            //and more and more
             }
}
});
```

Comment: I don't get it. rowData.Name and rowDataID does nothing. You have no semicolon on those lines either.